# Why does this code print the sine curve upside down

Tags: c, windows, winapi, screen, trigonometry

The y values generated seem correct.  See printf print out which prints increasing y vals.  But when sent to SetPixel function it seems to print the sin e curve as if multiplied by -1???

What is wrong?

```
#include <windows.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    HWND console = GetConsoleWindow();
    HDC dc = GetDC(console);
    int pixel =0;
    COLORREF C1= RGB(255,0,0); /* red */
    for (double i = 0; i< 6.3; i+=0.05)
    {
        SetPixel(dc,pixel,(int)(100+50*sin(i)),C1);
        /*printf("%d ", (int)(100+50*sin(i))); // prints numbers as expected, eg 100 102 104 107 109 112 etc */
        pixel+=1;
    } 
    ReleaseDC(console, dc);
    return 0;
}
```

AFTER FEEDBACK

Due to Windows co-ordinate system starting (0,0) at top left you can just change sign of sin function like this:

SetPixel(dc,pixel,(int)(100+50*-sin(i)),C1);

That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinate system isn't quite what you're expecting: `y == 0` is the *top*, not the bottom, of the screen.

See [Windows Coordinate System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The x-coordinates increase to the right; **y-coordinates increase from top to bottom**.

The [following](http://www.oopweb.com/Java/Documents/ThinkCSJav/Volume/chap04.htm) illustrates it nicely (it talks about Java coordinates, but Windows coordinates are the same):

[image: Coordinate systems]

An easy way to work around this is to flip the sign of `sin()`:

```
    SetPixel(dc,pixel,(int)(100-50*sin(i)),C1);
                               ↑
```